# Allocate more than 2GB on the heap using c++ on a 32bit linux kernel

Tags: c++, linux, x86, heap-memory, 32bit-64bit

This seems to be a very common problem, but still I haven't found a definite answer.

I have access to a server which runs linux, has 16 GB of RAM and a 16-core (64bit) CPU
(/proc/cpuinfo gives "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5520  @ 2.27GHz"). However, the kernel
is 32bit (uname -m gives i686). Of course, I have no root access, so I cannot change
that.

I am running a C++-program I wrote, which does some memory-hungry calculations, so I
I need a big heap - but whenever I try to allocate more than 2GB, I get a badalloc,
although ulimit returns "unlimited".
For simplicity, let's just say my program is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > vv;
    for (;;) {
        ++i;
        vv.resize(vv.size() + 1);
        std::vector<int>* v = &(vv.at(vv.size() - 1));
        v->resize(1024 * 1024 * 128);
        std::cout << i * 512 << " MB.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling with g++ (no flags), the output is:

```
512 MB.
1024 MB.
1536 MB.
2048 MB.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

As far as I understand, this is a limitation of 32bit systems, apparently because a 32bit pointer
can just hold 2^32 different adresses (Am I right to suppose that if I compiled the same program
on the same server, but that server ran a 64bit kernel, than the program could allocate more than
2GB?)

This is not a question of whether the allocated memory is contiguous, if I slice thinner in the
example program, the same problem occurs, and in my actual program, there are no big blocks of
memory, just many small ones.

So my question is:
Is there anything I can do? I cannot change the OS, but of course I could modify my source code,
use different compiler options etc. ...
but I do need more than 2GB of memory, all at once, and there is no obvious way to further optimise
the algorithm the program uses.

If the answer is a clear "no", it would still be good to know that.

Thanks,
Lukas

Comment: (1) Use a 64bit OS and native application. (2) Enable [Physical Address Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension#Operating_system_support) support on the target machine if it is 32bit. This should buy you an additional gB to work with. Short of that (which it appears you're pinned to some pretty narrow possibilities) a self-managed disk paging system may be your only option.

Comment: *Am I right to suppose that if I compiled the same program on the same server, but that server ran a 64bit kernel, than the program could allocate more than 2GB?* - Yes. You *may* be able to eek a little bit more out (perhaps up to 3.5Gb or so) with switches etc. Essentially, though you've hit a scalability issue and if you really can't find away to split processing by time or process to avoid hitting the limit then you'll have to move to 64 bit.

Comment: Could he get around this problem by having multiple processes allocate 2GB each. Then invent an IPC mechanism to read/write data to the memory chunks of the other process as needed? Or just run one or more instances of memcached?

Comment: @WhozCraig: PAE doesn't increase user-space virtual address space size, or C implementation limits on the size of a single object.  (In GNU systems, it's PTRDIFF_MAX, so the max object size is 2GiB on a 32-bit system - see [What is the maximum size of an array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/85864410)).  I assume in 2013 a 16GiB server running a 32-bit kernel was already using PAE.  The only option is to use a 64-bit system.  (If you truly couldn't replace the OS, qemu can emulate x86-64 on x86, but of course it won't be fast, having to page to disk to use more than 3GiB.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need the memory *all at once*, no, there is really no way to do it without changing to a 64-bit kernel (which, yes, would allow you to allocate more memory in a single process)

That said, if you don't need the memory all at once, but instead just with fast access, you can always offload parts of the memory storage to another process.

That could for example work by storing the data in the other process, and have your process temporarily map shared memory from that process into its own memory space when required. It will still be stored in-memory, but you'll have some overhead when switching memory range. If the overhead is acceptable or not would depend on your memory access patterns.

It's not a very straight forward approach, but without changing the kernel to give you a 64-bit address space, it sounds like you're in a bit of a bind.

EDIT: You may be able to raise the limit a little above 2GB by reconfiguring the kernel, but that only means you'll hit the hard limit there instead. Also, that would require root access.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a clear "No". If you can't change the OS, you can't raise the limit. The limit applies for a whole process and obviously no single allocation can exceed the per-process limit.

Depending on options used to compile the kernel, the limit could be higher than 2GB, but will certainly be less than 4GB. But I guess recompiling the kernel also counts as "changing the OS".

See [this discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/330994/maximum-memory-allocation-for-32bit-linux-kernel)

And yes, on a 64-bit OS that limit would go away.